# Estimating a sum with an integral to nearest power of $10$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, summation

Suppose I want to estimate the sum $\sum_{x = -1000}^{1000} \sum_{y: x^2 + y^2 < 10^6 } x^2$, or identically, $\sum_{y = -1000}^{1000} \sum_{x: x^2 + y^2 < 10^6 } x^2$, to the nearest power of $10$.

The hint is to estimate the sum with integrals, so perhaps I thought they mean $ \int\int_{x^2 + y^2 < 10^6} x^2 dx dy$, and this is on the order of $10^{12}$, which is the correct answer. However, since the integral is really a lower bound for the sum, why can we be sure that the answer is $10^{12}$?

(In the question I was solving, $10^{15}$ was the only other choice. Maybe one justification is that, given that information, it should be unreasonable that the sum deviates from the integral by a factor of $10^3$, but this isn't really convincing.)

Answer (score 2):

Let's restrict to the points where $x\geq 0$ so we are looking at the sum
$$\sum_{x=0}^{1000} \sum_{y : x^2 + y^2 < 10^6} x^2.$$
This is an Riemann sum over $\mathbb{R}^2$ over the squares $[n,n+1] \times [m,m+1]$ ($n \geq 0$) of the function $f(x,y) = x^21_{\{x \geq 0, x^2 + y^2 \leq 10^6\}}(x,y)$, inside the domain $\{x \geq 0, x^2 + y^2 \leq 10^6\}.$ Incidentally, we've actually picked a lower riemann sum (we are picking the leftmost value on the square $[n,n+1] \times [m,m+1]$,) so the integral is an overapproximation of our desired sum.

Let's compute an upper riemann sum and find the difference between them:
$$\sum_{x=0}^{1000} 2(x+1)^2 + \left(\sum_{y : x^2 + y^2 < 10^6} (x+1)^2  \right)$$
The $2(x+1)^2$ term comes from considering the square $[n,n+1] \times [m,m+1]$ that intersects the boundary of the circle $x^2 + y^2 = 10^6$: the smallest value of $f(x,y)$ on this square is 0, but the largest value will be $(n+1)^2$. The second term is what we would expect, it's the riemann sum over the squares strictly inside $\{(x,y) : x^2 + y^2 < 10^6, x \geq 0\}$.

Assuming we constructed the upper approximation correctly, let's find the differences between our upper riemann sum and our lower riemann sum:
$$\sum_{x=0}^{1000}\left[ 2(x+1)^2 + \left(\sum_{y : x^2 + y^2 < 10^6} (x+1)^2 \right)\right] - \sum_{x=0}^{1000} \sum_{y : x^2 + y^2 < 10^6} x^2 \leq \left(\sum_{x=0}^{1000} 2(x+1)^2\right) + 1001^2. $$

The above uses telescoping. Using a super coarse bound of
$$\sum_{x=0}^{1000} 2(x+1)^2 \leq 2*1000*1001^2,$$ the number on the right is less than $3*1001^3 \sim 10^{10}.$ Since the integral falls in between the left hand and right hand sum, this tells us that our sum is in between roughly $[10^{12} - 2*10^{10}, 10^{12}]$, so we are right to make the approximation. I'm sure there is a much tighter way of bounding this (maybe I am adding too many terms,) but the point is to show that our estimate holds.

A quick and dirty way of estimating this difference between the upper and lower Riemann sums is to look at the arc length along the boundary of our domain and approximate the boundary terms that go along with it: this is roughly $2 \pi 1000$ units in length, and our maximum value of our function on this boundary is $1000^2$. Hopefully, this contribution to our sum is $\sim 6 \cdot 10^9$. I am making a couple of assumptions (the length corresponds to the number of squares I am summing over) but this method could work well in a pinch?

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer! Just wanted to clarify some things: (1) the outcome of your first method is that $L \leq \int \leq U$, $\int \sim 10^{12}$ and $U-L \leq 10^9$ imply $ 10^{12} - 2 \times 10^{10} \leq L \leq  10^{12}$ (where $L, \int, U$ represent lower Riemann sum, integral and upper Riemann sum, resp.). I'm not sure how this gets the lower bound on $L$. Could you clarify?

Comment: Also, why do we have to seperately account for the square intersecting the boundary of the circle? My impression was that that would already be encountered when, for fixed $x$, we sum over the last $y$ such that $x^2 + y^2 < 10^6$?

Comment: Lastly, about your last suggestion in the final paragraph: that is still not close to 10^12, so we'd still need to do some work to make this argument work, I think?

Comment: For the first comment, you said it correctly. We have an interval $[L,U]$ where $U-L \leq 10^9$. If $\int \in [L,U]$, then $\int$ minus the length of the interval is necessarily outside of the interval, which tells us $\int - \;(U- L) \leq L \implies \int \;- 10^9 \leq L.$ (Also please forgive me for this notation).

Comment: For the second comment, I really wanted to be sure that I didn't miss anything so I included it. E.g., consider $x = 1000, y = 0.$ This is not included in the sum you wrote above, but it should be included in the upper riemann sum, which is where I think this extra terms pop up.

Comment: For the last paragraph, I am aiming to find a quick way to bound $U -L$ without actually writing the sums and ensuring that I've actually written an upper and lower Riemann sum. I've made this clarification in the answer.